# Wordpress images don't get displayed

Tags: php, wordpress

I started to learn **Wordpress** and I'm making my own theme. Within the design I have some images that are supposed to show up... but they don't.

I was using this code:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/html_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>
```

and then I found I should use **php** to link to my image:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>html_brand.jpg" 
                  class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

But the problem is, the image still doesn't get displayed. And yes I did upload them to my web server. I have them in the directory of my theme: `mythemename/images/html_brand.jpg`

Comment: <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/html_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>

Comment: thats not valid , use this : `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/images/html_brand.jpg`

Comment: if not work then use this one <a href=""><img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/slide_1.gif" class="slide" alt="" /></a>

Comment: No, still not showing up

Comment: replace with  this one now <?php bloginfo('template_url');?>

Comment: okay works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bloginfo()` to output your theme path, you need to add another `/`, followed by the remaining path to your image. Based on where you've placed your image, this should work:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/html_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

However, `bloginfo()` ultimately relies on `get_template_directory_uri()` to work, so you might as well just use that:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/html_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

**Slight Correction:**

`bloginfo()` with the specific argument of `stylesheet_directory` actually relies on `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to function -- `get_template_directory_uri()` like I originally said.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L439